# how to send image from django server to react native?

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

Currently, I send an image to django from react-native through my API, then save a new image on django. I would like to send that image back as a response to the API request. Currently I have tried to convert the image to base64 and send that back, but then I get an error on my iPhone that `PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`

Here is where the request is processed and response is sent back to the client:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def predict(request):
    try:
        file = request.data['file']
    except KeyError:
        return Response({'file': ['no file']}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    result = predictCentering(file.temporary_file_path())

    return Response(result, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

And this is where the `result` comes from:

```
cv2.imwrite("saved.jpeg", img)
with open("saved.jpeg", "rb") as image_file: # noqa
        image_data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
return [center_props, image_data]
```

`center_props` works fine, `image_data` does not. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should respond the Image URL, NOT the image data/file to client. I saw you tagged Django Rest Framework, so this is my suggestion:

Install `Pillow`.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):

  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
  ...
```

serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = ['image',]
```

**viewsets.py**

```
class SomethingViewSet(...):

  ...
  @api_view(['POST'])
  @permission_classes((AllowAny,))
  def predict(request):
    file = ... # make sure has image file
    serializer = ImageSerializer(image=file)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    
    return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
```

The response data like this:

```
{
  "image": "http://example.com/users/image-name.jpg"
}
```